# Adding SSH Key to authorized_keys: permission denied(publickey)

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket, ssh-keys

- I have an `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` on my computer also tied into my BitBucket account.
- As I understand I can use this public key anywhere I please *(as long as my private matches).*

**The Problem**: I cannot figure out how to get any server to accept the public key, do you see what I've done wrong?

```
 $ cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys

 $ service ssh restart  (I suppose this isn't needed)

 $ git pull origin master

 $ Permission denied(publickey)
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been stuck for days.

Comment: Did you run all those commands on the same machine? Putting the key in `authorized_keys` means you can log in to _that machine_ with that key, it doesn't help use that key to log in to _other_ machines. And you must have the private key on the local machine as well to push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the content of id_rsa.pub to the bitbucket avcount  its in the settings page

For more info https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/How+to+install+a+public+key+on+your+Bitbucket+account

Comment: If my local `id_rsa.pub` were not in BitBucket, I could not push to it from my hard drive. But I cannot from any server. Is what I said true?

Comment: Its a different key ?

Comment: Adding your public key to a server's authorized_keys allows you to login to that server using your private key. You would need to put your private key (or better, a new deployment keypair also added to bitbucket) on the server in order to pull from bitbucket from the server.

Comment: @cjc343, no, you put your **public** key on the bitbucket server

Comment: I wasn't claiming otherwise. OP seems confused about which key needs to be on a server pulling/cloning from bitbucket. I can see how the parenthetical could be read to mean both though.

Comment: page is 404 (not found)

Answer (score 26):

If you copied your root's `authorized_keys` you may have to do more than you are used to:

```
chmod 700 .ssh
sudo chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown $USER .ssh
sudo chown $USER .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Where `$USER` is your linux username.

Comment: After an hour+ of searching I finally found this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the permissions on `~/.ssh` are `700` i.e. only accessible by the owner, and the permissions on the public and private key files are not writable except by the owner.

Make sure the key files are in `~/.ssh` !

Make sure the key is being used (try ssh'ing to the right user @ the bitbucket server using `ssh -v`)

Comment: i think "Permission denied(publickey)" is returned from  the server, The key seems to be being used

Comment: No, that doesn't mean the key is being used. Use `ssh -v` to see what's used. There are several other tips for debugging this error at https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey (I know that's github not bitbucket, but the page is about ssh in general) and at https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=302811860 but of course you already read them because you searched the web before asking, right? ;)

Comment: try it yourself 0 i cant replicate his output by just changing permissions

Comment: But that doesn't mean the key is being used. Just because what I suggested isn't the answer doesn't mean there isn't another problem preventing the key being used.